# How to load data in chunks from a pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have read data in chunks over a pyodbc connection using something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("Some connection Details")
sql = "SELECT * from TABLES;"
df1 = pd.read_sql(sql,conn,chunksize=10)
```

Now I want to read all these chunks into one single spark dataframe using something like:

```
i = 0
for chunk in df1:
    if i==0:
        df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk)
    else:
        df2.unionAll(sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk))
    i = i+1
```

The problem is when i do a `df2.count()` i get the result as 10 which means only the i=0 case is working.Is this a bug with unionAll. Am i doing something wrong here??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`.unionAll()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll) states that it returns a new dataframe so you'd have to assign back to the `df2` DataFrame:

```
i = 0
for chunk in df1:
    if i==0:
        df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk)
    else:
        df2 = df2.unionAll(sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk))
    i = i+1
```

Furthermore you can instead use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to avoid having to manage the `i` variable yourself:

```
for i,chunk in enumerate(df1):
    if i == 0:
        df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk)
    else:
        df2 = df2.unionAll(sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk))
```

Furthermore the documentation for `.unionAll()` states that `.unionAll()` is deprecated and now you should use [`.union()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) which acts like UNION ALL in SQL:

```
for i,chunk in enumerate(df1):
    if i == 0:
        df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk)
    else:
        df2 = df2.union(sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk))
```

Edit:
Furthermore I'll stop saying furthermore but not before I say furthermore: As @zero323 says let's not use `.union()` in a loop. Let's instead do something like:

```
def unionAll(*dfs):
    ' by @zero323 from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33744540/42346 '
    first, *rest = dfs  # Python 3.x, for 2.x you'll have to unpack manually
    return first.sql_ctx.createDataFrame(
        first.sql_ctx._sc.union([df.rdd for df in dfs]),
        first.schema
    )

df_list = []
for chunk in df1:
    df_list.append(sqlContext.createDataFrame(chunk))

df_all = unionAll(df_list)
```

Comment: Furthermore you should really think twice before using `union(All)` in loop :) Hint: there is such thing like lineage out there.

Comment: @zero323: I will suggest that the OP create a list then pass that list to `.union()`...

Comment: This will work only with RDDs so you'll need a little bit more code. You can also truncate but it is ugly in Python.

Comment: @zero323: please see edit and let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no varargs version of `union`. You can check the last snippet in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33744540/1560062 which is still suboptimal but doesn't use private API. Also there is this https://github.com/high-performance-spark/high-performance-spark-examples/blob/master/high_performance_pyspark/SQLLineage.py

Comment: @zero323: thanks! I have incorporated your code -- with attribution and an upvote -- into my answer.

Comment: But by creating a df_list of all the chunks, wont you load all the chunks into memory at once. Chunks are primarily used so that we can load a table in small parts